# create html from 2-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, html

what is the best way to generate Html from 2-dimensional array

```
["red", 2 ]
["blue", 3]
["red", 5 ]
["blue", 1]
```

output Html

```
●●
○○○
●●●●●
○
```

javascript

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var result = arr[i][0] == 'red' ? '●' : '○';
    var output = '<tr><td>'+ result +'</td></tr>';
    $('table').append(output);
    for(var j = 0; j < $tArr[i][j].length; l++) {
        // how can I use following 2d data add more balls?
    }
}
```

not like this:

```
●
○
●
○
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use for loop there, you have number of balls as the second element in the array.
Using `str.repeat(count)`:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var ball = arr[i][0] == 'red' ? '●' : '○';
    // 'string'.repeat(N) returns 'string' repeated N times
    var result = ball.repeat(arr[i][1]);
    var output = '<tr><td>'+ result +'</td></tr>';
    $('table').append(output);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! What if I want to turn to vertical? I will open another quiz.